# same weblogic data source used by different applications

Tags: database-connection, datasource, weblogic-10.x

I have seen in weblogic admin console the same datasource with multiple JNDI names
These JNDI names are then referred in different applications

So my understanding is - the same datasource is being used by different applications deployed

Now my question is - lets say one application leaks jdbc connections ( does not close connections - so they never get returned back to the pool ) - will the other applications get impacted in this case ?

or will the server create separate connection pools for each application ?

Thanks
satish

Answer (score 0):

All applications will share the same connections from the pool, so one application that leaks connections will affect the other applications as well. Each application does not get its own pool unless you create a separate datasource with a different JNDI name.